How to connect this CM4 to a display and reinstall os?
I have this gridxbox which is a raspberry pi CM4. To function it only required power input via type c port and lan cable connected to lan port.
https://www.gridx.ai/edge-services
Would like repurpose it and connect it to a display to see the terminal. This is a new device and is functional.
Things I tried

When I connect it to PC (tried both windows and Ubuntu) the emmc flash drive doesn't get mounted automatically. tired both USB c and A ports.

Tired connecting a display with built-in usb c cable to usb c port. Its then says displayport connected but nothing is visible on the screen.

used pi imager to update bootloader and flash new image but not sure it worked or not because I cannot connect to display and raspberrypi
local doesn't show anything running


Sometimes green and red lights flash
Questions

how to connect this to a display?
how to flash a new pi os to it?
what is the black port circled in red? can I use it connect to display?




If ultimately you want to run HA, I would suggest getting a RPi4 and using the HA ISO image for that RPi. I 1st wanted to run HA on the same RPi3 I had my MQTT server running on. Then it became apparent most HA help was at a higher level and the details of a scratch HA are... less well written about. So I used a separate RPi3 and the HA ISO for a RPi3. That worked until I needed to configure/control a Sonoff NSPanel. Then it became apparent the RPi3 didn't have enough memory. So I switched to a RPi4. But the ISOs are written for specific RPis. So I needed to start over w/the RPi4 HA ISO image.

Agree. I would like to reinstall the pi os. Do you know to connect this to a display and reinstall os? Because currently I cannot flash os and see the display

There's a not unreasonable chance whatever was on the board originally was a custom system designed to work with the hardware it's attached to -- not necessarily proprietary, but you won't be able to reverse engineer the set-up which would include things like a device tree overlay.   The board only has HDMI for display output, so something special may be going on if the gridxbox use(d) a USB-C connector for that...  If you've flashed it properly and that doesn't work, well, debugging it is going to be impossible w/o a display and keyboard or ssh connection.  Probably the end.

I couldn't flash it properly because pi imager doesn't recognize the flash drive of cm4. do you know what is the port circled in red?

Even if you did reinstall the RPi/CM's OS, you would have to install HA from scratch. As the HA ISO images are made for specific RPi's and I don't think there's one for a RPi/CM. That's why I'm suggesting if you want to run HA, I think the easiest way is to buy a new RPi4 and use the HA RPi4 ISO image. OTOH, if you are good w/docker (I think that's what HA uses), then go for it. As for that connector, looks much more likely that is a power port. But I've never seen that RPi/CM carrier card before.  And can't find anything similar on the web.

Usually, a carrier board would have a switch/jumper to allow flashing a CM4 - marked something like RPIboot or similar. I can't see anything like that in the picture. Perhaps that carrier board was designed to only house CM4-lite's - i.e. ones with a SD slot.

Q: 1 & 3: It can not be connect to a display. The circled connector is a serial port.
Interfaces

2x USB 2.0
10/100 MBit Ethernet
optional: RS232, RS485, RJ12, CAN-Bus, IO-Link

Q: 2: To connect this CM4 to a display and reinstall OS would need a Raspberry Pi CM4 Carrier (Base) Board. See instructions https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/compute-module.html#flash-compute-module-emmc for OS installations (skip IO Board as that is different from your CM4).
